# How to pass the in-line editable mat-table data into the service using angular8?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I have prepared the editable dynamic column/rows Mat-Table. I have entered the data into the each cell. After Click on submit button how to get/iterate formArray/formgroup data (like json) and construct json object to send to the service. I am unalbe to get this,Could you please help on this?

Link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zazofh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "onSaveClick()" method if you use "this.myformArray.value" it will return an array of objects. Which is pretty versatile for making a post request or sending the data elsewhere. You can also use methods JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() to get the formatted JSON data.